# Web Api Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, geojson

I am Consuming web api service from one project (project1) to another project (project2) but when i try to get the response from project2 to project1 with this code

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
  string json = URL;
  Var jdownload = client.DownloadString(json);
}
```

It's adding back slashed into "jdownload" Var please guide me how i can get that response without that backslashes

i.e

```
  “servicefor” = “GetData”,     
    “settings” = {
                     \"stringname\":5, 
                     \"url\":\"null",
                    \"services\":\"GetSet\",
                    \"interval\":2.0,
                    \"alldatacontains\":200,                
                    \"netamountname\":\"BulkFetch\"
                 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution how can i get the Clean Jason

```
       public JObject GetData(string dataO)
        {
            var data = MethodToGetData(dataO);
            JObject pobj = JObject.FromObject(new
            {
                type = "stgdats",
                val = "val",
                d_id = id,
                sat = data
            }
                );
            return pobj;
        }
```